# Swagger does not work for nested objects (Apex, Oracle)

Tags: oracle, rest, swagger, oracle-apex, oracle-rest-data-services

I'm trying to generate swagger documentation via Oracle -Apex. Nested JSON objects either do not appear on documentation or cause error in swagger:
[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPilo.png)

Is there any way for swagger to generate the correct documentation when there are nested objects in the code or can it be maybe overwritten somehow?

Here is an example of a JSON object that generates an error:

````sql
    v_sql_dane:='with
                    table_name3 as (   
                                     select
                                           rowid
                                     from table_name
                                     where 1 = 1 ' || v_where_firstname || v_where_lastname || v_where_gender || v_where_age || '  
                                     order by rowid
                                     OFFSET :b5 ROWS FETCH FIRST :b6 ROWS ONLY
                                  )  
                    select 
                           json_arrayagg(json_object(''TEMP_PERSON_UUID''             VALUE TEMP_PERSON_UUID, 
                                                     ''FIRST_NAME''                   VALUE FIRST_NAME,
                                                     ''LAST_NAME''                    VALUE LAST_NAME,
                                                     ''GENDER''                       VALUE GENDER,
                                                     ''AGE''                          VALUE AGE,
                                                     ''CALCULATED_DEGREE_TITLE''      VALUE CALCULATED_DEGREE_TITLE,                   
                                                     ''EMPLOYMENT_INSTITUTION_NAMES'' VALUE EMPLOYMENT_INSTITUTION_NAME format json 
                                                     returning clob ) 
                                         format json returning clob),
                            count(1)
                     from table_name3 
                              join table_name
                                    on column_name1 = column_name2';
    ```
````

Comment: all of the errors shown are related to path parameters, not the json object response payload. you have defined path parameters in the `parameters` array but you didn't include them in your uri pattern.  I have a feeling you marked `limit`, `offset` etc.. as `required` but they need not be required. They should also use the syntax `in: query` rather than `in: path`.